# If a group $G \cong H$, and if $H$ is a simple group, is $G$ also a simple group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

I know that is the case, but I asked this question because I cannot find a formal way to prove it. Something is missing in my mind, I don't know what, that's why I asked the question. I don't expect a comprehensive proof, just a hint would be enough.

Comment: Do you know what it means for two groups to be isomorphic, not on a formal level but on an intuitive level?

Comment: @mrtaurho Yes. (just to fill up with characters)

Comment: Then I'm a little puzzled that you asked this question. Of coure, as presented by *Fovios* a formal proof is doable but unnecessary from an intuitive POV (at least IMO).

Comment: @mrtaurho Yes for you, but not for me.

Comment: If two groups are isomorphic they're the same up to renaming the elements. Thus, every property (like being simple) one of both has immediately transfers to the other one aswell. That's at least how I think (intuitively) about isomorphic groups.

Comment: @mrtaurho I know.

Comment: Then, with all due respect, why did you've asked the question in the first place?

Comment: @mrtaurho Because I want to see the proof.

Comment: The proof is trivial. Rename so that $G=H$. Done. Why do you ask the other more advanced questions when you need a proof even for this? You could start practising more basic questions first.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Then it's great for you, but like I said not for me.

Comment: No, for me it doesn't matter. I mean, it will certainly help you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde No worry any more though, I've been blocked to post another question. That's ok, but I just don't get it. The site told me that my low level questions are impacting its quality, which is that means downvotes from you all decide it. What I don't get is what kind of quality we are talking about? Is it about the quality of helping other people to learn, or is it about a community of 1st rate mathematicians solving 1st rate of mathematical problems?

Comment: Your question is fine; the way it was formulated not completely. MSE encourages questions of *all* levels (in contrast to MO), that is true. Anyway, what is expected from users who ask questions is to show some effort. That is, show what you have tried, where you failed to continue, etc. pp. Your question was formuated as an isolated problem, without any context why you asked for a proof and in particular without any hint on your own backround (this is reflected in the two answers given, which approach the question on different levels). Such questions are discouraged by the community.

Comment: @mrtaurho You are right with your idea, but my idea is different. When you're learning, it's not necessarily true that you have to try to answer every single building blocks by yourself. You may stumble on something that you know the answer is already there somewhere, why don't just simply ask. It doesn't need to be answered thoroughly but even as simple as a hint would do, it's fast and makes the job done. Someone thinks it's too trivial, fine, skip it. Putting those kind of restrictions and bureaucracy is what an open community wants to break in the first place. That's my idea of community.

Comment: I have done enought self-learning to understand your point of view. On the other hand I am about two years around on MSE and also understand why these restrictions are in place. Allowing question of the kind "Please show me a proof for that" or "Do this for me" would lead to an imbalance. Everyone here is participating voluntary and the least a person with a question can do is to respect this and thereby formulating their question accordingly: that is, include your backround, include your attempts and point out what exactly you do not understand. That way someone can help you even better.

Comment: @mrtaurho That I could understand. But who are we to judge the intention of someone asking? And who are we to judge that no one else willing to answer the question? And what kind of imbalance that you mean? I mean, isn't it that the site owner wants this site to be the first place to look for for someone looking for help? Yeah, may be not, I don't know. Anw I realize it's neither me nor you, but the way this site is designed, and so now I understand why it is said the way it is said.

Comment: Making the intention clear is up to the person asking a question by formulating an actual question and not just stating an isolated problem; anyway, just keep these (arguably sometimes weird) regulations in mind when asking questions in the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am probably overexplaining things, but here 's a detailed argument.

Let $G$ and $K$ isomorphic groups and let $H$ normal subgroup of $G$ and suppose $\phi:G\to K$  is the isomorphism. You want to prove that $\phi(H)$ is normal subgroup of $K$. So let $x\in K$. We need to prove that $x\phi(H)x^{-1} \subset \phi(H)$. But $\phi$ surjective, so there exists $g\in G$ such that $\phi(g)=x$. Therefore $$x\phi(H)x^{-1}=\phi(g)\phi(H)\phi(g)^{-1}=\phi(gHg^{-1})=\phi(H)$$ which is what we wanted.

I leave it up to you to prove that $\phi(H)$ is proper, non trivial (note that in the above we used only the fact that $\phi$ is surjective, you will need to use injectivity to prove it's proper, non trivial).
If you take the contrapositive of what we just proved, you got what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Now I can use it to assume that $\phi(H) = {1}$ and get a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Of course.  If $H$ and $G$ are isomorphic, they are for all intents and purposes the same group.

Comment: Would you mind to give a hint of how to prove it?

Comment: Ok.  Since you have an isomorphism, a normal subgroup of $G$ corresponds to a normal subgroup of $H$.  Better, though, is that they are the same group.

Comment: What if $G$ and $H$ are (isomorphic) subgroups of one same parent group? I don't think in this case "they are for all intents and purposes the same group" works.

Comment: I know what you mean.  But they share all the same group theoretic properties.  They might, for instance, be Sylow subgroups.  So different but isomorphic, in as much as they have different elements. @user750041

Comment: So, the Klein four group has three "copies" of $\Bbb Z_2$.  And so on. @user750041